# Destructuring nested objects as function parameters

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

In ES6 we can do:

```
let myFunc = ({name}) => {
  console.log(name)
}

myFunc({name:'fred'}) // => logs 'fred'
```

But how do I do it for nested properties like this:

```
myFunc({event:{target:{name:'fred'}}}) // => I want it to log 'fred'
```

What should myFunc look like so that it logs 'fred'?

I cannot change the object passed in. I wish to use destructuring to achieve this or some other suitable ES6 approach.

Comment: Do you know the structure of `name`?  Or are you wanting to log all values?

Comment: the object structure is show ... event.target.name ... i just want to log the value of event.target.name using ES6 destructuring if possible

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can simply do like this:

```js
const myFunc = ({event: {target: {name}}}) => {
  console.log(name)
}

myFunc({event: {target: {name: 'fred'}}})
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Here is an other implementation, with both in parameters, but the second is entirely optionnal:

```js
const myFunc = (
      {name: name},
      {event: {target: {name: eventTargetName = ''} = ''} = ''} = ''
    ) => {
      console.log(name, eventTargetName)
    }

myFunc({name:'fred'})
myFunc({name:'papi'}, {event: {target: {name: 'fredo'}}})
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```js
let myFunc = ({ event: { target: { name } } }) => {
  console.log(name);
};

myFunc({ event: { target: { name:'fred' } } }); // => logs 'fred'
```

See also [examples on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Unpacking_fields_from_objects_passed_as_function_parameter).

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```js
let myFunc = ( obj ) => {
    console.log(obj.event.target.name);
};

myFunc({ event: { target: { name: 'fred' } } });
```

Or:

```js
let myFunc = ( {event: {target: { name } } } ) => {
    console.log(name);
};

myFunc({ event: { target: { name: 'fred' } } });
```

Comment: OP asked for solution with destructuring or some other ES 6 approach.